# Disable an md-input

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I would like to disable the input under certain conditions.
Show the value, but not beeing able to modify it.

I tried to add an ng disable, or ng class, but it doesn't look to work for me.

```html
<div ng-controller="SettingsController">
    <md-input-container ng-class="{'md-block' : model.isDisable" ng-disabled="model.isDisabled">
        <input ng-model="obj.name" aria-label="name" />
    </md-input-container> 
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/cReJQlhNOBzB7VihhRS5?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your **ng-disabled** to the input tag. It should work.

```
<div ng-controller="SettingsController">
      <md-input-container ng-class="{'md-block' : model.isDisable" >
          <input ng-model="obj.name" aria-label="name" ng-disabled="model.isDisabled" />
      </md-input-container>

</div>
```

Also there is an out-of-place '{' in the ng-class that bothers me but the code still works so I didn't change it since I don't know if it is necessary.